# finding matches fitting between 2 date operations

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to find all `Patients.dob` that are between `Patient.dob - 20`, and `patient.dob -30` (in years).

I am using Oracle 10g, and have tried `dateAdd` and tried substituting  `SYSTIME - 12*30` but neither works.

The data is loaded fine and is in the date format as it should be.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the year and do a between (but this way only gets the year difference, no necessary the exact 20-30 year difference)

```
with datam as
(
 select level id, sysdate - level dob
   from dual 
 connect by level < 15000)

 select count(id) count_id , extract(year from dob)
   from datam
  where extract(year from dob) between 2011-30 and 2011-20
  group by extract(year from dob)
  order by 2 desc
```

but, ignoring leap years (this is what you were trying to do with the 12*30, it should have been 365*12)

```
with datam as
(
 select level id, sysdate - level dob
   from dual 
 connect by level < 15000)

 select count(id) count_id , extract(year from dob)
   from datam
  where dob between (sysdate - 365*30) and (sysdate - 365*20)
  group by extract(year from dob)
  order by 2 desc ;
```

But @Briguy37 works as well:

```
with datam as
(
 select level id, sysdate - level dob
   from dual 
 connect by level < 15000)

 select count(id) count_id , extract(year from dob)
   from datam
  where dob between add_months(dob,- 12*30) and add_months(sysdate,- 12*20)
  group by extract(year from dob)
  order by 2 desc ;
```

Comment: is there any reason why this code:

WHERE  add_months("Patients"."Patient_DOB", -30*12) <= "Patients"."Patient_DOB" AND add_months("Patients"."Patient_DOB", -20*12) >= "Patients"."Patient_DOB";

returns no data found?? and there are values present that shud be returned

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_months to do it:

```
select * from patient p 
  where 
    add_months(p.dob,30 * 12) > current_date and 
    add_months(p.dob,20 * 12) < current_date;
```

Comment: Note:  The reason it was not working to subtract directly is because that calculation is figured in days.

Comment: Don't you want negative values for the constants? E.g., add_months(p.dob,-20*12)

Comment: @DCookie If you take the example of someone born on 01/01/1990, they are currently 21, and thus the statement needs to be true for them.  Adding 20 and 30 years respectively gives you 01/01/2010 and 01/01/2020, and the current date of 05/13/2011 is between those dates, so it holds true.  You'd need to subtract if you were doing the operations on the current date, like idkWATimDOIN was doing in the question.